# Attempt to reformat rpi 3 by wiping the SD card clean

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, noobs

I am trying to factory reset my rpi 3, to continue using it for a new application. I have searched around on ways to do this and it seems like downloading NOOBS or Raspbian on the card is the way to go. I am new to this world, and so here what my impression of the process is:

1. put the rpi SD card into an adapter and into my Mac
2. format the card using disk utilities
3. download NOOBS/Raspbian (what is recommended) and place it on the
   card
4. insert the card back into the Pi
5. boot up the Pi and hope for the best!

Is this an effective procedure?

Kindly advice on what would need changes?

Comment: Since you specified "Mac," I would recommend downloading the [Raspbian image](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) and using the [MacOSx instructions](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/mac.md)  ... IMO, the `noobs` image can be a little more complex to work around if someone wishes to tinker a little with the OS configuration.

Comment: As you are rewriting the image to the SD card and hence have nothing to lose (but a few minutes time) why not just try it?

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to install Raspbian (which I strongly recommend over NOOBS) there is **NO NEED** to format the SD Card, just overwrite the old image.

Again, I strongly recommend you use `Etcher` rather than `dd`. It neatly avoids the possible problems with installing on the wrong device.